# what does this ABaddressBook NSLog Mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nslog, abaddressbook

I am trying to search the AddressBook for Phone Numbers by name,

```
-(void)textMessage{
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSMutableArray *array;
    for(int i = 0;i<[savedPeople count];i++){
        array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:savedPeople]objectAtIndex:i];
        CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (CFStringRef)array);
        NSLog(@"%@",people);
    }
}
```

and i get a log of this

```
2012-05-01 09:22:31.688 UpOut[5829:15803] (
    "<CPRecord: 0x84edf90 ABPerson>"
)
2012-05-01 09:22:31.694 UpOut[5829:15803] (
    "<CPRecord: 0x84ee1c0 ABPerson>"
)
```

I dont know what the string in the middle mean, did it return correctly??

### EDIT

```
for(NSString *name in savedPeople){
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (CFStringRef)name);
    CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)people, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSLog(@"%@",phoneProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is an [ABPerson](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) record.

Your code is doing what you want but is written very badly, `[[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:savedPeople]objectAtIndex:i];` is a NSString, not an array.

```
for(NSString *name in savedPeople)
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (CFStringRef)name);
```

To extract values from `ABPerson` check out the documentation. For example:

```
CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)people, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Comment: ahhh okay, but how would i change it to display the names/phonenumber data?

Comment: i get a breakpoint with your code, i have edited my post also

Comment: FYI: The Cocoa/Core Foundation memory guidelines state that you need to balance function with `copy` in their name with a release call! So you are effectively leaking memory there